# Search box in Vb.net using Sqlite Database

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, runtime-error

My code for searchbox in my application does not work, no matter what i do it gives me the same error, and some additional information saying "Additional information: Cannot find column [p_name]" i don't know what's wrong or why can't it find my column
here's my code:

```
   Private Sub nameSearchbox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nameSearchbox.TextChanged

    Dim DV As New DataView(dt)

    DV.RowFilter = "[p_name] LIKE '%" & nameSearchbox.Text & "%' AND [t_date] LIKE '%" & dateSearchbox.Text & "%'"
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DV

End Sub
```

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e48Fy.png)

Comment: Why do you think that the column `p_name` actually exists?

Comment: ahm, because it's a column name in my database?

Comment: According to the error message, this is not actually the case. Do you have any evidence for the opposite?

Comment: what do you mean opposite sir?

Comment: this code actually works before i changed everything from Mysql to Sqlite

Comment: The only possible reason for this error is that the table does not have a `p_name` column. Since you have not given any information about the database or the table, it is your job to find out why.

Comment: edited my post and i added a link image of my database

Comment: and of course the column exists cause i can add data under that column name

Comment: Then you are not using that database file, or not that table.